# mysqlsh in Python mode, cannot import modules

Tags: python, pandas, import

New to Mysqlsh I'm trying to import module pandas, but I'm getting:

```
 MySQL  Py > import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas

Mysqlsh ver. 8.0.11
Python ver. 2.7.15
Updated OSX
```

I can import pandas in Python, and must admit, that I know nothing about dependencies between Python and MySQL Shell

Answer (score 0):

Your module has to be in one of those paths listed by `sys.path`.

```
 MySQL  Py > import sys
 MySQL  Py > sys.path
```

Install `pandas` globally, or append your `pandas` install path to `sys.path` in `mysqlsh`.

Comment: I added path to syspath, and mysqlsh is now able to find pandas. However, I get this error now:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Import from Anaconda Python works fine. Can import pandas and numpy.